# How to give persiomission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or WRITE in android 6.0

Tags: android

I am trying to show badge on app icon when notification came from server.

I am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider from ProcessRecord{ab1124 10588:com.rehq.app/u0a175} (pid=10588, uid=10175) requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 6.0 you need to request permissions at Runtime before you need them.

The example below is for the WRITE permission (I guess you'd like to add a badge to the app icon and normally you don't need the READ permission for this - if you need it you can request it just like the WRITE permission)

First add your permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>
```

Then you can check if they are granted at Runtime like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M 
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //permissions not granted -> request them
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS}, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
} else {
        //permissions are granted - do your stuff here :)
}
```

The result will be available in `onRequestPermissionResult`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //permissions granted -> do your stuff ;-)
        }
        //Permission not granted -> react to it!
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

You can read more about it in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: no worries - please accept it if it helped you to solve the issue?

Comment: If you allow than i want to ask one question regarding fcm badge?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really experienced with that.. I just know about the permissions ;-) but I can try it - but it would be better if you ask it in a seperate question